(javascript object), set same value to next value if greater than previous value, And versa
i have list of object ,
i want to compare value id to next value, if less than previous value, assign new key named IDS and set value to "1", why exactly (1), because its started from first object in array.
is same thing in case the next value is greater than previous value.
This is what I can explain.
For parts (4, 5) and (2 ,3) I find it difficult to explain this part.
and thank you in advance.
let lists = [
  { price:10, id:1},
  { price:11, id:2},
  { price:12, id:3},
  { price:13, id:4},
  { price:14, id:5},

  { price:12, id:4},//this part
  { price:12, id:5},//this part

  { price:11, id:4},
  { price:10, id:3},
  { price:9,  id:2},

  { price:12, id:3},//this part
  { price:12, id:2},//this part
]

Result:
let lists = [
  { price:10, id:1, IDS:1 },
  { price:11, id:2, IDS:1 },
  { price:12, id:3, IDS:1 },
  { price:13, id:4, IDS:1 },
  { price:14, id:5, IDS:1 },

  { price:12, id:4, IDS:2 },
  { price:12, id:5, IDS:2 },

  { price:11, id:4, IDS:3 },
  { price:10, id:3, IDS:3 },
  { price:9,  id:2, IDS:3 },

  { price:12, id:3, IDS:4 },
  { price:12, id:2, IDS:4 },
]


can you explain little more what you exactly need.

The list changes, so I don't know if the id values are smaller than the previous values or vice versa.
I want to set a new IDS key, when the id value is greater than the previous value. Example:
id:1 is smaller than id:2 to id:5.
So we set IDS:1
And id:4 is greater than id:3.
So we set IDS:2
Every time the values change from larger to smaller, we increase the number in the IDS

You could use an object for incrementing a group value and a max value to prevent smaller group values.


const
    group = (group, max) => o => {
        max = group[o.id] = Math.max((group[o.id] || 0) + 1, max);
        return { ...o, IDS: max };
    },
    lists = [{ price: 10, id: 1 }, { price: 11, id: 2 }, { price: 12, id: 3 }, { price: 13, id: 4 }, { price: 14, id: 5 }, { price: 12, id: 4 }, { price: 12, id: 5 }, { price: 11, id: 4 }, { price: 10, id: 3 }, { price: 9,  id: 2 }, { price: 12, id: 3 }, { price: 12, id: 2 }],
    result = lists.map(group({}, 0));

console.log(result);
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }




nothing to improve so far...

Thank you very much, very good and very helpful, and very clean code.
